# How to analyse categorical data?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data

First off I would like to apologise for the ill-defined nature of the question, I have very little background in statistics and am currently taking a post-grad stats paper.

My variable of interest is unordered categorical, with two possible outcomes. The other factors (50+) share these qualities. In all honesty I don't really know where to start, if anyone could a) outline the process I should be following or b) direct me to some resources that will educate me, that'd be great.

The data is genetic data with sex, ethnicity and 50+ SNPs. The aim admittedly hasn't been provided, however intuitively I assume we are looking at whether any of the SNPs have a significant effect on the outcome of interest. (I.e is the outcome of interest more likely in someone with 'SNP x') - we also need to establish a hypothetical causal diagram.

Thank you!

Comment: It is hard to know how to analyze any data, categorical or not, without knowing what your goals are. What is it you would like to learn from these data?

Comment: You definitely can (and IMHO should) start with [exploratory data analysis (EDA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis). Having said that, it would be better, if you'd have a clear understanding of what _types of analysis_ would you need to perform next (_regression_, etc.). For this, I think it would be beneficial to first **describe** and then **frame** your problem, followed by stating some **research questions**.

Comment: Is outcome categorical? What are the "SNPs"? Also notice that if the data does not come from experimental research, but rather from observational, there is no information that would enable you to identify casual relations but only correlational.

Comment: Yep, the outcome is categorical (binary), as are the SNPs (single nucleotide polymorphisms). Thanks for that, I'll be sure to keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your outcome variable has only 2 possible values, then you should consider [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). This procedure uses the log of the odds of one of the 2 possible outcomes as the equivalent of a dependent variable in standard linear regression, with your other variables (age, sex, ethnicity, status of SNPs, etc) as the independent variables.

As in standard linear regression, the independent variables can be continuous or categorical. Unlike standard linear regression there is no closed-form formula to calculate the regression coefficients; programs to calculate logistic regression optimize the coefficients to best match the observed data. The `glm` function in the R computing environment provides tools for logistic regression. [This page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Logistic_regression/) shows some examples of how to proceed.

As @Tim notes in a comment, however, you will not be able to identify causal relations, only correlations.